# tableView.contentInset broken on iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

Setting the contentInset on a UITableView doesn't seem to work on iOS 7:

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 100, 0); 
// Works on iOS 6, nothing happens on iOS 7
```

I've tried setting `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `NO` in viewDidLoad, still nothing.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a new way to do this or a workaround?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Moving this code into the view controller's `-viewDidLayoutSubviews` method fixed this for me.

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 100, 0); 
}
```

Thanks Apple for your non-existent documentation on this!

Comment: Thanks for this, it seems the default content inset isn't set in viewWillAppear but it is by the time this method is called. I was trying to move a view to the bottom of the screen and this helped.